# Make C++ Task class similiar to C#'s Task

Tags: c++, asynchronous, c++14, task-parallel-library

I am enjoying making various programs with C++.

This is my first code review request. And I hope I can get some insights or might have good advice to make my code better.

I make a task class using C++14 standards after having insights of System.Threading.Task class of C#.

Although I could not make a perfectly same codes with those C# asynchrounus task operation (async-await syntax), I implement task class like C# Task's basic function operations.

### Concept

- Task has 'callable' object (called by operator())
- Task is submitted by std::async (C++ standard parallel library will handle tasks...)
- Task can be canceled, continued or wait.
- Task can have child task by its continuation function(then).

### Code Design

- All functionalities are hid with 'block' which controls the state of a task.
- Use shared_ptr inside so that task[T] class can be used as a value type
- Callable object was type erased by inheritance like boost::any

### task.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <memory>
#include <atomic>
#include <vector>

#include "function_traits.h"
namespace cpptask
{
    template<typename F, typename ...Args>
    struct func_wrapper : callable_t<typename gen_task_type<F, Args...>::Return>
    {
        using ThisType = func_wrapper<F, Args...>;
        using FuncType = typename gen_task_type<F, Args...>::Func;
        using TupleType = typename gen_task_type<F, Args...>::Tuple;
        using ReturnType = typename gen_task_type<F, Args...>::Return;
        using BaseType = callable_t<ReturnType>;

        FuncType func;
        TupleType params;

        func_wrapper(F&& f, Args&&... args) : func(std::forward<F>(f)), params(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}

        ReturnType operator()() const override { return const_cast<ThisType*>(this)->call_fn(std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<TupleType>>()); }

        template<size_t ...Is>
        ReturnType call_fn(std::index_sequence<Is...>) { return func(std::get<Is>(std::forward<TupleType>(params))...); }
    };

    template<typename F, typename ...Args>
    static auto make_func_wrapper(F&& f, Args&&... args) { return func_wrapper<F, Args...>(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...); }

    template<typename F, typename ...Args>
    static typename func_wrapper<F, Args...>::BaseType* make_func_wrapper_pointer(F&& f, Args&&... args) { return new func_wrapper<F, Args...>(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...); }

    enum task_status
    {
        created,
        running,
        completed,
        canceled,
        faulted,
    };

    class task_cancelled : public std::exception {
    public:
        task_cancelled() = default;

        const char* what() const override {
            return "a task was cancelled";
        }
    };
    
    class aggregate_exception : public std::exception {
        template<typename T>
        friend class dispatch_block;
    private:
        std::vector<std::exception> inner_exceptions;

    public:
        auto begin() { return inner_exceptions.begin(); }
        auto begin() const { return inner_exceptions.begin(); }
        auto end() { return inner_exceptions.end(); }
        auto end() const { return inner_exceptions.end(); }

        size_t size() const { return inner_exceptions.size(); }

        aggregate_exception() = default;

        const char* what() const override {
            return "aggregate exception";
        }

        void add_exception(const std::exception& e) {
            inner_exceptions.push_back(e);
        }

        void add_exception(const aggregate_exception& es) {
            for (const auto& e : es) {
                inner_exceptions.push_back(e);
            }
        }
    };

    struct cancel_block {
        std::atomic<bool> canceled;
        cancel_block() : canceled(false) {}
        void cancel() { canceled.exchange(true); }
    };

    class cancellation_token {
    private:
        std::shared_ptr<cancel_block> block;

    public:
        cancellation_token() = default;

        cancellation_token(const std::shared_ptr<cancel_block>& blockIn) : block(blockIn) {}

        bool is_cancellation_requested() const { if (block == nullptr) return false; return block->canceled; }

        void throw_if_cancellation_requested() const { if (block != nullptr && block->canceled) throw task_cancelled(); }
    };

    class cancellation_token_source {
        friend class cancellation_token;
    private:
        std::shared_ptr<cancel_block> impl;

    public:
        cancellation_token_source() : impl(std::make_shared<cancel_block>()) {}

        cancellation_token token() { return { impl }; }

        std::shared_ptr<cancel_block> _block() const { return impl; }

        void cancel() { impl->cancel(); }
    };

    template<typename T>
    class task_awaiter;

    template<typename T>
    class task_base;

    template<typename T>
    class task;

    struct task_t {
        virtual void wait() = 0;

        virtual void dispatch() = 0;
    };

    class child_disaptch_block {
    private:
        struct one_time_event {
            std::promise<void> p;
            std::future<void> f;

            one_time_event() : f(p.get_future()) {}

            void set() { p.set_value(); }
            void wait() { f.wait(); }
        };
        bool dispatched;
        std::mutex mtx;
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<task_t>> childs;
        std::unique_ptr<one_time_event> child_would_dispatch;

    protected:
        bool is_self_child;

        child_disaptch_block(bool child)
            :
            is_self_child(child),
            dispatched(false)
        {
            if (is_self_child) {
                child_would_dispatch = std::make_unique<one_time_event>();
            }
        }

        void wait_if_is_self_child() {
            if (child_would_dispatch) {
                child_would_dispatch->wait();
            }
        }

        void dispatched_if_is_self_child() {
            if (child_would_dispatch) {
                child_would_dispatch->set();
            }
        }

        template<typename T>
        bool add_child(const task<T>& child) {
            std::unique_ptr<task_t> task_pointer(new task<T>(child));
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mtx);
            if (!dispatched) {
                childs.push_back(std::move(task_pointer));
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<task_t>> mark_dispatch() {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mtx);
            if (dispatched) {
                throw std::logic_error("child tasks already dispatched");
            }
            dispatched = true;

            return std::move(childs);
        }
    };

    template<typename T>
    class dispatch_block : public child_disaptch_block
    {
        friend class task_base<T>;
        friend class task<T>;
        friend class task_awaiter<T>;
    private:
        task_status status;
        cancellation_token cancel_token;
        std::shared_ptr<aggregate_exception> exception_ptr;

        std::atomic<bool> dispatch_once;
        std::future<void> dispatch_token;

        std::promise<T> result_token_setter;
        std::future<T> result_token;

    public:
        dispatch_block(const cancellation_token& token, const bool& child_in) 
            : 
            child_disaptch_block(child_in),
            status(created),
            cancel_token(token),
            dispatch_once(false),
            result_token_setter{},
            result_token(result_token_setter.get_future()),
            exception_ptr(nullptr)
        {}

        dispatch_block(const bool& child_in) : dispatch_block(cancellation_token{}, child_in) {}
        dispatch_block() : dispatch_block(false) {}

        void add_exception(const std::exception& e) {
            if (exception_ptr == nullptr) {
                exception_ptr = std::make_shared<aggregate_exception>();
            }
            exception_ptr->add_exception(e);
        }

        void add_exception(const aggregate_exception& e) {
            if (exception_ptr == nullptr) {
                exception_ptr = std::make_shared<aggregate_exception>();
            }
            exception_ptr->add_exception(e);
        }

        bool has_exception() const {
            if (exception_ptr != nullptr) {
                return exception_ptr->size() != 0;
            }
            return false;
        }

        const aggregate_exception& exception() const {
            if (exception_ptr == nullptr) {
                const static aggregate_exception empty;
                return empty;
            }

            return *exception_ptr;
        }

        bool is_child() const { return is_self_child; }

        bool is_canceled() const { return cancel_token.is_cancellation_requested(); }

        bool is_dispatchable() { 
            bool expected = false; 
            return dispatch_once.compare_exchange_strong(expected, true); 
        }

        void set_dispatched(std::future<void>&& dispatch_token_in) {
            status = running;
            dispatch_token = std::move(dispatch_token_in);
            dispatched_if_is_self_child();
        }
    };

    template<typename T>
    class task_base : public task_t
    {
    protected:
        std::shared_ptr<callable_t<T>> callable;
        std::shared_ptr<dispatch_block<T>> signal;

    protected:
        task_base(callable_t<T>* const& callableIn, bool child = false)
            :
            callable(callableIn),
            signal(std::make_shared<dispatch_block<T>>(child))
        {
        }

        task_base(callable_t<T>* const& callableIn, const cancellation_token& token, bool child = false)
            :
            callable(callableIn),
            signal(std::make_shared<dispatch_block<T>>(token, child))
        {
        }

        task_base(const task_base& rhs) {
            callable = rhs.callable;
            signal = rhs.signal;
        }

        task_base& operator=(const task_base& rhs) {
            callable = rhs.callable;
            signal = rhs.signal;
            return *this;
        }

        task_base(task_base&& rhs) noexcept {
            callable = std::move(rhs.callable);
            signal = std::move(rhs.signal);
        }

        task_base& operator=(task_base&& rhs) noexcept {
            callable = std::move(rhs.callable);
            signal = std::move(rhs.signal);
            return *this;
        }

        template<typename T>
        bool add_child(const task<T>& child) {
            return signal->add_child(child);
        }

        void dispatch_child() {
            auto childs = signal->mark_dispatch();
            for (auto& child : childs) {
                child->dispatch();
            }
        }

        void throw_if_child_task() {
            if (signal->is_child()) {
                throw std::logic_error("start child task");
            }
        }

    public:
        const aggregate_exception& exception() const {
            return signal->exception();
        }

        virtual void operator()() = 0;

        virtual void wait() override {
            signal->wait_if_is_self_child();
            signal->dispatch_token.wait();
        }

        bool is_canceled() const { return signal->status == canceled; }

        bool is_completed() const { return signal->status > running; }

        bool is_faulted() const { return signal->status == faulted; }

        bool is_completed_sucessfully() const { return signal->status == completed; }

        task_status get_status() const { return signal->status; }

        task_awaiter<T> get_awaiter() const { return { signal }; }
    };

    template<typename T>
    class task : public task_base<T>
    {
    public:
        task(callable_t<T>* const& callableIn, bool child = false) : task_base<T>(callableIn, child)
        {}

        task(callable_t<T>* const& callableIn, const cancellation_token& token, bool child = false) : task_base<T>(callableIn, token, child)
        {}

        virtual void operator()() override {
            auto& signal_obj = task_base<T>::signal;
            try {
                if (signal_obj->is_canceled()) {
                    throw task_cancelled();
                }
                else {
                    T&& value = (*task_base<T>::callable)();
                    if (signal_obj->is_canceled()) {
                        throw task_cancelled();
                    }

                    signal_obj->status = completed;
                    signal_obj->result_token_setter.set_value(std::forward<T>(value));
                }
            }
            catch (const task_cancelled& e) {
                signal_obj->add_exception(e);
                signal_obj->status = canceled;
                signal_obj->result_token_setter.set_exception(std::current_exception());
            }
            catch (const aggregate_exception& e) {
                signal_obj->add_exception(e);
                signal_obj->status = faulted;
                signal_obj->result_token_setter.set_exception(std::current_exception());
            }
            catch (const std::exception& e) {
                signal_obj->add_exception(e);
                signal_obj->status = faulted;
                signal_obj->result_token_setter.set_exception(std::current_exception());
            }

            task_base<T>::dispatch_child();
        }

        virtual void dispatch() override {
            if (task_base<T>::signal->is_dispatchable()) {
                task_base<T>::signal->set_dispatched(std::async(std::launch::async, [task_obj = *this]() mutable { (task_obj)(); }));
            }
            else {
                throw std::exception("task is already started");
            }
        }

        void start() {
            task_base<T>::throw_if_child_task();
            dispatch();
        }

        template<typename F, typename R = std::decay_t<typename function_traits<std::decay_t<F>>::ReturnType>,
            typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<typename decay_tuple_type<typename function_traits<std::decay_t<F>>::FArgsType>::type, std::tuple<task<T>>>>>
        task<R> then(F&& fIn);

        T get() { return task_base<T>::signal->result_token.get(); }
    };

    template<>
    class task<void> : public task_base<void>
    {
    public:
        task(callable_t<void>* const& callableIn, bool child = false) : task_base<void>(callableIn, child)
        {}

        task(callable_t<void>* const& callableIn, const cancellation_token& token, bool child = false) : task_base<void>(callableIn, token, child)
        {}

        virtual void operator()() override {
            auto& signal_obj = task_base<void>::signal;
            try {
                if (signal_obj->is_canceled()) {
                    throw task_cancelled();
                }
                else {
                    (*task_base<void>::callable)();
                    if (signal_obj->is_canceled()) {
                        throw task_cancelled();
                    }

                    signal_obj->status = completed;
                    signal_obj->result_token_setter.set_value();
                }
            }
            catch (const task_cancelled& e) {
                signal_obj->add_exception(e);
                signal_obj->status = canceled;
                signal_obj->result_token_setter.set_exception(std::current_exception());
            }
            catch (const aggregate_exception& e) {
                signal_obj->add_exception(e);
                signal_obj->status = faulted;
                signal_obj->result_token_setter.set_exception(std::current_exception());
            }
            catch (const std::exception& e) {
                signal_obj->add_exception(e);
                signal_obj->status = faulted;
                signal_obj->result_token_setter.set_exception(std::current_exception());
            }

            task_base<void>::dispatch_child();
        }

        virtual void dispatch() override {
            if (task_base<void>::signal->is_dispatchable()) {
                task_base<void>::signal->set_dispatched(std::async(std::launch::async, [task_obj = *this]() mutable { (task_obj)(); }));
            } else {
                throw std::exception("task is already started");
            }
        }

        void start() {
            throw_if_child_task();
            dispatch();
        }

        template<typename F, typename R = std::decay_t<typename function_traits<std::decay_t<F>>::ReturnType>,
            typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<typename decay_tuple_type<typename function_traits<std::decay_t<F>>::FArgsType>::type, std::tuple<task<void>>>>>
        task<R> then(F&& fIn);

        void get() { task_base<void>::signal->result_token.get(); }
    };

    template<typename T>
    class task_awaiter {
    private:
        std::shared_ptr<dispatch_block<T>> signal;

    public:
        task_awaiter(const std::shared_ptr<dispatch_block<T>>& signalIn) : signal(signalIn) {}

        bool is_completed() { return signal->status > running; }

        T get_result() { return signal->result_token.get(); }
    };

    template<typename F, typename ...Args>
    static inline auto make_task(F&& f, Args&&... args)
    {
        return task<typename func_wrapper<F, Args...>::ReturnType>(make_func_wrapper_pointer(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    }

    template<typename F, typename ...Args>
    static inline auto make_task_with_cancellation_token(const cancellation_token& token, F&& f, Args&&... args)
    {
        return task<typename func_wrapper<F, Args...>::ReturnType>(make_func_wrapper_pointer(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...), token);
    }

    template<typename F, typename ...Args>
    static inline auto run_async(F&& f, Args&&... args)
    {
        auto task_source = make_task(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        auto fire_and_forget = std::async(std::launch::async, [](auto&& task_obj) { task_obj.dispatch(); }, task_source);

        return task_source;
    }

    template<typename T> template<typename F, typename R, typename>
    task<R> task<T>::then(F&& fIn)
    {
        auto entangled = [f = std::forward<F>(fIn), task_obj = *this]() mutable {
            task_obj.wait();
            return f(task_obj);
        };

        auto child_task = task<R>(make_func_wrapper_pointer(entangled), true);
        if (!task_base<T>::add_child(child_task))
        {
            child_task.dispatch();
        }

        return child_task;
    }

    template<typename F, typename R, typename>
    task<R> task<void>::then(F&& fIn)
    {
        auto entangled = [f = std::forward<F>(fIn), task_obj = *this]() mutable {
            task_obj.wait();
            return f(task_obj);
        };

        auto child_task = task<R>(make_func_wrapper_pointer(entangled), true);
        if (!task_base<void>::add_child(child_task))
        {
            child_task.dispatch();
        }

        return child_task;
    }
}
```

### function_traits.h

```
#pragma once
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

namespace cpptask
{
    template<typename... Ts> struct make_void { typedef void type; };
    template<typename... Ts> using void_t = typename make_void<Ts...>::type;

    template<typename R>
    struct callable_t
    {
        virtual R operator()() const = 0;
    };

    template <typename T, typename = void>
    struct function_traits : function_traits<std::decay_t<T>> {};

    template <typename R, typename... A>
    struct function_traits<R(A...)>
    {
        using ReturnType = R;
        using ClassType = void;
        using ArgsType = std::tuple<A...>;
        using FArgsType = std::tuple<A...>;
    };

    template <typename R, typename... A>
    struct function_traits<R(*)(A...)>
    {
        using ReturnType = R;
        using ClassType = void;
        using ArgsType = std::tuple<A...>;
        using FArgsType = std::tuple<A...>;
    };

    template <typename R, typename C, typename... A>
    struct function_traits<R(C::*)(A...)>
    {
        using ReturnType = R;
        using ClassType = C;
        using ArgsType = std::tuple<A...>;
        using FArgsType = std::tuple<C*, A...>;
    };

    template <typename R, typename C, typename... A>
    struct function_traits<R(C::*)(A...) const>
    {
        using ReturnType = R;
        using ClassType = C;
        using ArgsType = std::tuple<A...>;
        using FArgsType = std::tuple<const C*, A...>;
    };

    template <typename T>
    struct function_traits<T, void_t<decltype(&T::operator())>>
        : public function_traits<decltype(&T::operator())> // for lambda
    {
        using FArgsType = typename function_traits<decltype(&T::operator())>::ArgsType;
    };

    template<typename R, typename T>
    struct gen_func_type
    {
        using type = void;
    };

    template<typename R, typename ...Args>
    struct gen_func_type<R, std::tuple<Args...>>
    {
        using type = std::function<R(Args...)>;
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct gen_param_type
    {
        using type = std::remove_reference_t<std::remove_cv_t<T>>;
    };

    template<typename ...Args>
    struct decay_tuple_type
    {
        using type = std::tuple<Args...>;
    };

    template<typename ...Args>
    struct decay_tuple_type<std::tuple<Args...>>
    {
        using type = std::tuple<std::decay_t<Args>...>;
    };

    template<typename T>
    using gen_param_type_t = typename gen_param_type<T>::type;

    template<typename F, typename ...Args>
    struct gen_task_type
    {
        using Return = std::decay_t<typename function_traits<std::decay_t<F>>::ReturnType>;
        using FArgs = typename function_traits<std::decay_t<F>>::FArgsType;
        using Func = typename gen_func_type<Return, FArgs>::type;
        using Tuple = std::tuple<gen_param_type_t<Args>...>;
    };
}
```

### Here is my example !

- Launch a Task

  ```cpp
  auto t1 = run_async([]() {
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
      throw std::exception("noop");
  });
  ```

  ```csharp
  var t1 = Task.Run(async () =>
  {
      await Task.Delay(2000);
      throw new Exception("noop");
  });
  ```
- Continue with the other task, can be cancelled or faulted by exception.

  ```cpp
  auto t2 = t1.then([](task<void>& t) {
      if (t.is_faulted())
      {
          cout << "previous task was faulted by exception" << endl;
      }
      else {
          cout << "not faulted by exception" << endl;
      }
  });
  ```

  ```csharp
  var t2 = t1.ContinueWith((t) =>
  {
      if (t.IsFaulted)
      {
          Console.WriteLine("previous task was faulted by exception");
      }
      else
      {
          Console.WriteLine("not faulted by exception");
      }
  });
  ```

Comment: I like it :). Would you care if I used this? You obviously put a lot of work into this which is pretty awesome dude.

Answer (score 1):

## Make more use of the standard library

This is a nice idea, a `.next()` function is something not supported by C++11's `std::async()`, or rather the [`std::future`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future) object you get from calling `std::async()`. However, your code looks quite complex, and it seems like you are duplicating a lot of the details that are inside of `std::async` and `std::future` already. What is missing from `std::future` is the ability to share its state, however C++11 also gave us [`std::shared_future`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_future). Consider this ghetto implementation of a similar `run_async()`:

```
#include <future>

template<class T>
struct continuable_future: public std::shared_future<T> {
    continuable_future(std::shared_future<T> future): std::shared_future<T>(future) {}

    template<class Function, class... Args>
    auto then(Function f, Args... args) {
        auto continuation = [=, parent = *this]{
            parent.wait();
            return f(args...);
        };
        return continuable(std::async(continuation).share());
    }
};

template<class Function, class... Args>
auto run_async(Function f, Args... args) {
    return continuable_future(std::async(f, args...).share());
}
```

This is already enough to run code like:

```
auto t1 = run_async([]{
    std::cout << "t1 start\n";
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    std::cout << "t1 end\n";
    return 42;
});

auto t2 = t1.then([t1](auto msg){
    std::cout << "t2 start, t1 returned" << t1.get() < "\n";
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    std::cout << "t2 end, " << msg << "\n";
}, "bye bye!");
```

Note that my `then()` accepts the same kind of arguments as `run_async()`. If you want to access the results of the parent task, you can pass it via lambda capture or as a parameter. You could also consider always passing the parent task as the first parameter, and append any other parameters after that.

The above code is of course missing constructor overloads, doesn't do perfect forwarding, and is missing support for cancellation and fault detection.

Note that `std::future` and friends store exceptions as well, trying to call `std::get()` on a future whose task `throw`ed one will cause that same exception to be thrown in the thread calling `std::get()`.

As for cancellation, it might be tempting to put that into `continuable_future`, however it would not be in the shared block, so it's not safe to access from the async task. I don't see a way to support that easily without having to reimplement a shared block for this information yourself.